# How can I make a backup of data I don't have permission for?

Tags: fedora, permissions, boot, backup

Fedora doesn't boot anymore, so I need to make a backup of my data before running boot-repair. The thing is: I can't acess my fedora-personal files from boot-repair as I don't have permission.
How can I make a backup of them then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your live CD, try to log in as **root** in order to copy the data. Or use su/sudo su in a terminal window.

Comment: sudo did the trick, thanks. Unlike su, it doesn't ask for a password on boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live CD and mount the HD where you have the data to copy it to an external HD.